# Windows Phone navigating between pages in different folders

Tags: c#, xaml, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone, directory

views->passwordscreen->password.xaml

views->homepage.xaml

I navigate from homepage to the password.xaml page using

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/views/passwordscreen/password.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

however I cant navigate from password to homepage, ive tried a few ways, how can I do this?

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/views/homepage.xaml", UriKind.Relative)); //doesn't work

NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/homepage.xaml", UriKind.Relative)); //doesn't work
```

Exceptions: System.InvalidOperationException: No XAML was found at the location /homepage.xaml

Comment: what homepage location is?

Comment: homepage location is /views/homepage, but i tried that and it gives the same error, im trying to navigate out of the passwordscreen folder, how can i do this?

Comment: just check whether the names of pages are correct. I don't find any problem in the code written for navigations.

Answer (score 1):

I dont see any problem with this, Double check your folder paths and file name,

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/views/homepage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

Anyway you can do this since you want to go back to the same page,

```
   function void GoBack()
    {
     if (this.NavigationService.CanGoBack)
     {
      this.NavigationService.GoBack();
     }
    }
```